# Sort an oversized string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an oversized string array of emails. When I don't fill the oversized array with anything beforehand, I get a nullPointerException. When I fill the array with empty strings, my code sorts the list of emails alphabetically, but puts the sorted list of emails behind the empty strings. How do I sort the list of emails so that it first lists the emails alphabetically in the array and then lists the empty strings?

Example: If I entered example1@domain, example2@domain, star, and apple, the following quote would be my output. I want all of the empty strings to be behind the entered data, not before it.

> [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , apple, example1@domain, example2@domain, star]

Code:

```
String[] data = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];

public static String[] addEmail(String[] data, String email, int index) {
    int size = data.length;
    data[index] = email;

    int i,j;
    String temp;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    for (j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
      temp = data[j];
      i = j - 1;
      while (i >= 0) {
        if (temp.compareTo(data[i]) > 0) {
          break;
        }
        data[i + 1] = data[i];
        i--;
      }
      data[i + 1] = temp;
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));

    return data;
}
```

Edit: I have to code my own sort logic for "efficiency" in this project. I also have to use an oversized array.

Comment: Do your thing and add at the end a `System.arraycopy()` that copies the end of the array to the beginning of a new array, and fill the rest with empty strings. Boom!

Comment: Must you write your own sort logic? Are you allowed to use library functions like Arrays.sort()?

Comment: Do you have to sort the array manually? Normally Arrays.sort() does a pretty god job.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an oversized array. Use a `Collection`. Since you want it to be sorted I suggest a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). You might write something like

```
public static SortedSet<String> addEmail(SortedSet<String> coll,
        String email) {
    if (coll == null) {
        coll = new TreeSet<>();
    }
    coll.add(email);
    return coll;
}
```

If you really wanted to use `String[]` you could adapt the above algorithm like

```
public static String[] addEmail(String[] arr, String email) {
    SortedSet<String> coll = new TreeSet<>();
    if (arr != null) {
        coll.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
    }
    coll.add(email);
    return coll.toArray(new String[coll.size()]);
}
```

Comment: I agree this would be a great solution but I have to use my own sort logic and I have to use an oversized array in this project :(